# Apps for tracking iPhone app sales?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

Are there any free apps that will track your iPhone app sales?  Many have now gone to paid.

Comment: You're looking for a service that will display when an app is free? Or do you want to see your results in an app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has an official iTunes Connect app that can show your stats: [**iTunes Connect Mobile**](https://itunes.apple.com/app/itunes-connect-mobile/id376771144?mt=8)

[image]